# How to get comment ID via rest api in the Jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I need to get the comment content via code or script, and I found this [doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-issue-comment-properties/) and try it, but now, the latest issue is I cannot get the comment ID. Could you please help us to get the latest comment ID or list all comment ID via task ID. Thx.

What I tried:

API: `https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/comment/{commentId}/properties`

Java code:

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/comment/{commentId}/properties")
  .basicAuth("email@example.com", "<api_token>")
  .header("Accept", "application/json")
  .asJson();

System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

I have tried this api via postman, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it from the issue id or key.

First, [get the issue's comments](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/api-group-issue-comments/#api-rest-api-2-issue-issueidorkey-comment-post) via:

GET `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/comment`

Then, find the comment id from here and call

GET `/rest/api/2/comment/{commentId}/properties`

Update

The first API could get task details and then we need to use below API to get one of the comment.

```
rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/comment/{commentId}
```